# Random load of all rows in a loop with no duplication in PHP

Tags: php, sql, loops, random, rows

I have a while loop that loads data from a table row into a div.
After one row it loops and loads another row into a duplicate div and so on.

Now I want this loop to select rows at random but have exhausted all rows by the end without duplication.

I have rows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want (random order) rows:

```
3
2
5
1
4
```

basically load all rows but in random.
I am using PHP.

Comment: May not even need to pop it off, just shuffle and loop on it once building the html during that one loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably easiest to `ORDER BY RAND()`. You don't show your DB API or functions so replace the function names with what you use:

```
$result = your_query('SELECT some1, some2 FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND()');

while($row = your_fetch($result)) {
    //use $row in div
}
```

If you already have your rows in an array, then:

```
shuffle($rows);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    //use $row in div
}
```